# How to override drag and drop event in ckeditor

Tags: drag-and-drop, ckeditor

I need to some manual functionality while drag and drop the text. But I could not find the specific events to listen this event in ckeditor. Could you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor at the moment (1) doesn't provide any event or handles the drop actions in any way. Everything that you see is the default behavior of each browser.

So use the DOM and use your own listeners.

1: They plan to change this for the next version, but I can't foretell if they will provide what you want.